# Reduce hard voltage drops on mains?

Tags: ac, mains, stability, stabilizer

I'm experiencing some hard voltage drops on my AC power line (measured at 20 points across the house).
The culprits are the washing machine and dryer (as well as our upstairs neighbors washer and dryer). The drops are anywhere between 4V (from 244 to 240) to as much as 15 volts causing our monitors to flicker off for a hot second and our wifi to drop out for a little bit.

Is there anything that I can do to stretch out the voltage drop and prevent it from messing with my devices. I would like to check here before I take extreme measures and start building a power stabilizer for my router, monitors etc....

The voltages meters here need some further calibration. They are 30V too high.
Voltage next to the washer
[image: voltage next to washer]
Voltage next to the dryer
[image: voltage next to dryer]
Voltage in the living room
[image]
voltage in the bedroom
[image]
Voltage of the router (This one is properly calibrated and has a much higher refresh rate)
[image]
The sensors I use measure average over 2 seconds. The sensor at the router averages over 0.5 seconds.

Comment: The culprit is most likely wiring that is too small for the distance from the point where power comes into the house. Also, multiple machines powered by one circuit when they should be on separate circuits. Call an electrician.

Comment: The problem is most likely not the wiring itself but some faulty clamp. You should let an electrician check them all.

Comment: old wiring in the house with too few strands can explain this. It's probably not a 230V network problem.

Comment: Perhaps a fancy UPS can solve (mitigate) this problem?

Comment: I have a couple of 1F capacitors that I can put in series with the DC power supply of the router. I can 3D print a barrel jack in/out box quite easily. That should deal with the internet going out all the time. The monitors and PC's are harder to solve though.... a UPS would work but I'll have to estimate if that would be worth it with the extra wear on the PC's or if the power supply is dealing with it. So far I've not noticed anything wrong with the PC just the monitors. Unfortunately there is nothing I can do about the underground wiring due to the nature of the house.

Comment: I'll ask for a electrician to measure the resistance of the wiring just in case though. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no location information in your question or user profile but I'm assuming that you are in Europe.

4 V on a 240 V supply, which is 230 V nominal if you are in Europe, is nothing to be concerned about. European supply is supposed to be maintained at 230 V +10%/-6% so 216 V to 253 V.

It is more likely that you are experiencing a larger voltage drop than you can measure with your test equipment because it lasts < 1 s. A multimeter may smooth or average out several readings and won't catch the dip in voltage.

You shouldn't be seeing this problem. It is caused by the surge current on motor start-up causing a voltage drop on either a long supply line, a faulty (high-resistance) connection or overloaded supply transformer. If you are satisfied that your building wiring is OK then you should raise the matter with your supply company and request that they monitor your supply and rectify it if found defective.

Comment: Thanks. This building is well over 150 years old so I wouldn't be surprised if there is some faulty wiring somewhere underground (all the above ground wiring has been redone in the late 1980's early 1990's).

Answer (score 1):

I had similar fluctuations when I lived on an island, close to a ferry terminal. Whenever the flickering happened, there was a ferry passing the window.

The ferry wasn't interfering with anything, but the motors raising the linkspan at the pier (to match the state of the tide) were each larger than a refrigerator.

If you're in a rural area (weak supply) and/or very large intermittent consumer of power, this is possibly an incoming supply issue : simply run your computers and monitors off a power conditioner or better, an UPS. But I agree with the other answer that ruling out local wiring faults first.